# How to localize iOS icons

Tags: ios, icons

I see that I can upload specific 1k icon in itunes connect (appstore connect), but it is not cool if I localize only appstore icon (my app icon still will be unlocalized). What is the correct way to localize iOS icons? I read similar questions but all of them are outdated.

Comment: There is no simple way to localise icons. Apple's [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/) suggest avoiding words - ideally your icon should not require localisation - it is your app's identity.  Facebook's icon is the stylised 'f' even in non-roman locales.

Comment: Actually it's not about text, it's about color identity, it is very important to use specific color palette in different countries

Comment: Then you might find it is best to simply release specific versions in specific regions

Comment: I tried, but Apple says it's spam and I have to combine my apps in one :(

Comment: You could appeal; explain that specific versions are being released in specific stores; it can’t be spam if only one version is available in a given store (you have to manage the regional availability in App Store Connect). Ultimately, though, if Apple won’t approve that you will need to find one icon that you can use globally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do this automatically. You can however set alternative app icons manually using the following function:

```swift
func setAlternateIconName(_ alternateIconName: String?, 
        completionHandler: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil)
```

For more info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname

This, however, requires the user the start the app one time before you can change the app's icon to a localised version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unforunately in my case changing the icon after start can confuse users even more